# javascript to multiply product price and quantity

Tags: javascript

I write javascript code to multiply `product price` to the `quantity` input in the `input field` but it's not working can somebody have any idea where is the problem..

**javascript**

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

function multiply(){

a=Number(document.abc.QTY.value);

b=Number(document.abc.PPRICE.value);

c=a*b;

document.abc.TOTAL.value=c;

}
</script>
```

**form**

```
<input type="text" value="" name="QTY" id="QTY" onKeyUp="multiply()" /><br />

  <input type="text" name="PPRICE" id="PPRICE" value="<?php echo $product['pprice']; ?>" /><br />

  <input type="text" name="TOTAL" id="TOTAL" /><br />
```

Comment: seems working http://jsfiddle.net/qrkwmd2d/

Comment: what is `abc.`? it should be `getElementById()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite sure where you're getting `abc` from but you should be using `document.getElementById()`. Change your `function` code to the following and all will be well.

```
function multiply()
{
    // Get the input values
    a = Number(document.getElementById('QTY').value);
    b = Number(document.getElementById('PPRICE').value);

    // Do the multiplication
    c = a*b;

    // Set the value of the total
    document.getElementById('TOTAL').value=c;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    function hitungTotal(){
        var qty = document.getElementById("newQuantity").value;
        var price ="";
        var totPrice =qty * price;
        document.getElementById("newTotal").value = totPrice;
    }
```

Comment: It's better to include some context/explanation with code as this makes the answer more useful for the OP and for future readers.

Answer (score 0):

```
function total() {
        let qty = $('.qty').val();
        let price = $('.price').val()
        $('.total').val(qty * price)
    };
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value